# GeoServer create layer using SQL view failed -"cannot be cast to class org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore"

Tags: geoserver, layers

**1.** When I tried to create a new Geoserver layer from a new SQL view, after type the sql statement and all the parameters, when I click save, got the following saving error:

> Failed to create SQL view: class org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore cannot be cast to class org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore (org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore and org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @63fdab07)

[Here's a screenshot of how that same error message looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkJWU.png)

Here is the sql statement we use to create view on Geoserver and it has 2 parameters:

```
SELECT link_id, st_name,
CASE
WHEN %npi_id% = 1  THEN npi_1_cat
WHEN %npi_id% = 2  THEN npi_2_cat
WHEN %npi_id% = 3  THEN npi_3_cat
WHEN %npi_id% = 4  THEN npi_4_cat
WHEN %npi_id% = 5  THEN npi_5_cat
ELSE npi_1_cat
END as cond_cat,
geom
FROM tl_link_qid_npi5
WHERE q_id = %query_id%
```

[image: New Sql View Saving screen]

If we run the normal sql query on the view in database directly, it's fine and result been returned.

And also this is the log we got from Geoserver regarding to this exception:

```
[geoserver.web] - Failed to create feature type
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore cannot be cast to class org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore (org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore and org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @63fdab07)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.SQLViewNewPage.onSave(SQLViewNewPage.java:34)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.SQLViewAbstractPage$6.onSubmit(SQLViewAbstractPage.java:306)
    at ...
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor710.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore cannot be cast to class org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore (org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore and org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @63fdab07)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.SQLViewAbstractPage.testViewDefinition(SQLViewAbstractPage.java:351)
    ...
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    ... 122 more
An error occurred while loading the page
```

**2.** Also, when I tried to open some existing layers, if I click the '**Edit sql view**' button, I got the following exception message and it also stopped me to see the sql view setup.

Not sure will this help to identify the issue?

```
2023-01-23 01:46:10,461 WARN [org.geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: Unknown type tl_link_npi5_qid
2023-01-23 01:46:10,461 DEBUG [org.geoserver.catalog] - java.io.IOException: Unknown type tl_link_npi5_qid
        at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore.getSchema(RetypingDataStore.java:114)
        at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore.getSchema(RetypingDataStore.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore.getSchema(RetypingDataStore.java:47)
        ...
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    

2023-01-23 01:46:10,463 DEBUG [org.geoserver.catalog] - Unable to clean up cached feature type tl_link_npi5_qid in data store ToolboxAWS - not a ContentDataStore
2023-01-23 01:46:10,463 ERROR [org.geoserver.web.data.resource] - Grabbing the attribute list failed
    java.io.IOException: Unknown type tl_link_npi5_qid
        at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore.getSchema(RetypingDataStore.java:114)
        at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore.getSchema(RetypingDataStore.java:320)
        ...
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)




Unable to find component with id 'guessParams' in [Form [Component id = form]]
    Expected: 'form:guessParams'.
    Found with similar names: ''
 MarkupStream: [markup = jar:file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.19.0.jar!/org/geoserver/web/data/layer/SQLViewAbstractPage.html
<form wicket:id="form">

    <ul>
        <li><label for="name"><wicket:message key="name">name</wicket:message></label>
          <input type="text" wicket:id="name"/>
        </li>
        <li><label for="sqlDefinition"><wicket:message key="sqlDefinition">sql definition</wicket:message></label>
          <textarea rows="60" cols="20" wicket:id="sql"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li><label for="parameters"><wicket:message key="parameters">parameters</wicket:message></label>
            <a href="#" wicket:id="guessParams"><wicket:message key="guessParams">guess from sql</wicket:message></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" wicket:id="addNewParam"><wicket:message key="addNewParam">add new</wicket:message></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" wicket:id="removeParam"><wicket:message key="removeSelected">remove selected</wicket:message></a>
            <div wicket:id="parameters"></div>
            <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="escapeSql"/><wicket:message key="escapeSql">Escape special characters</wicket:message>
        </li>
        <li><label for="attributes"><wicket:message key="attributes">attributes</wicket:message></label>
            <a href="#" wicket:id="refresh"><wicket:message key="refresh">refresh</wicket:message></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span wicket:message="title:guessGeometrySridWarning"><input type="checkbox" wicket:id="guessGeometrySrid"/><wicket:message key="guessGeometrySrid">Guess geometry type and srid</wicket:message></span>
            <div wicket:id="attributes"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="button-group toolbar-sticky selfclear"><a href="#" class="form-button-save" wicket:id="save"><wicket:message key="save">Save</wicket:message></a> <a href="#" class="form-button-cancel" wicket:id="cancel"><wicket:message key="cancel">Cancel</wicket:message></a></div>
    </form>, index = 19, current =  '<a href="#" wicket:id="guessParams">' (line 0, column 0)]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupStream.throwMarkupException(MarkupStream.java:526)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.throwException(MarkupContainer.java:1620)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1539)
    ...     
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

What's the cause of this error, and how can the problem be resolved?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Hi, it's using postgres database

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I have edited the original post with more detailed error message I got from Geoserver, please have a look.

Comment: Do you possibly have some additional extensions loaded? That part about ToolboxAWS looks a bit strange.

Comment: Hi, anyway I can check that? I cannot see any additional extension using.

Comment: I noticed the error message also complained with 'wicket', eg: '<a href="#" wicket:id="guessParams">', not sure what's this?

Comment: what versions of GeoServer and Java are you using?

Comment: Hi Ian, the JAVA -> openjdk version "11.0.17" and Geoserver is 2.19.0; GeoTools Version 25.0; GeoWebCache Version 1.19.0